# ServiceProvider design pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns, silex

I'm working on a ServiceProvider build for the Silex framework and i have some questions about how i should organise my code (design pattern ect).
This is what i have so far:

> /Package
>   /Package/Classes
>   /Package/Controller
>   /Package/Model
>   /Package/Provider
>   /Package/Package.php

Now come's the part where i question about my code:
In the Package.php i have a class thats creating the other needed classes:
It's some kind of package builder i think..

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->content  = new ContentClass($this);
  $this->language = new LanguageClass($this);
}

public function content()
{
  return $this->content->getContent();
}

public function language()
{
  return $this->language->getLanguage();
}
```

In my ServiceProvider i can now do things like this:

```
public function register(Application $app)
{
  $app['package'] = $app->share(function($app)
  {
    return new Package();
  });

  $app['package.content']  = $app['package']->content();
  $app['package.language'] = $app['package']->language();
}
```

I don't think this is the correct way to do this.
I'm searching for a design pattern or something like that to organize my code the correct way.
 I hope some one could help me out with this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what else the Package.php class does, but you also could let the Provider build all necessary parts.
The benefit here would be that you can pass a config array to the provider to build a specific configuration.

You can use one of the many configProvider like https://github.com/igorw/ConfigServiceProvider to manage configuration in f.e. yaml.

F.e.:

```
package:
  content:
    config1: foo
    config2: bar
  language: de
```

and use the provider as builder:

```
public function register(Application $app)
{   
$app['package.content'] = $app->share(function($app)
  {
    return new ContentClass($app['package']['content']['config1'], $app['package']['content']['config2']);
  });
$app['package.language'] = $app->share(function($app)
  {
    return new LanguageClass($app['package']['language']);
  });
}
```